# Firebase firestore timestamp based security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

On my client side I am creating a document with one of the fields "createdDate"

below is a payload from the firestore simulator

```
{
  "__name__": "/databases/(default)/documents/billing/aaaa",
  "data": {
    "createdDate": 1529237500239,
    "createdDateTimeFormat": "2018-06-12T07:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

I tried to set the security rule to make sure the "createdDate" is not in the future.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /billing/{userId}{
        allow create: if (request.resource.data.createdDate < request.time.toMillis());
    }     
  }
}
```

This gives access denied.

Next, I tried the following rule referencing the Timestamp format. That gives access denied as well.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /billing/{userId}{
        allow create: if (request.resource.data.createdDateTimeFormat < request.time);
    }     
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't use a string like createdDateTimeFormat for date comparisons against `request.time`.  As I said in my answer, `request.time` is a Timestamp type object, which can only be compared to other Timestamp type objects from your documents.

Answer (score 4):

`request.time` is of type [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp), as you can see from the [rules reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time), but you're using it as a number.

You have two options.  First, you could change your createdDate field to a Timestamp type object, which is probably the better way to go.

If you must leave it as a number, you'll have to convert the `request.time` Timestamp object to a number that matches the measurement of your number.  If your number measured in milliseconds since epoch, you can use the [toMills()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp#toMillis) method on it:

```
allow create: if (request.resource.data.createdDate < request.time.toMillis());
```

Comment: I kept createdDate as a Number and tried < request.time.toMillis(). Access denied. I changed createdDate as a Timestamp and tried < request.time. Access denied.

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to show the code you're using to actually add this document?

Comment: What I want to see is the code on the client that you're using to add the documents.