# Firestore limit read snapshot by current time

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to display the last 10 messages of a conversation. Then as the conversation progresses, obviously, I need to show those messages as well:

I am doing something like this:

```
  //function a
  db.collection("conversations/" + messageID + "/messages").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").limit(10).
  get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  const time = Date.now();
  //call function b and pass time as a parameter

  //function b
  db.collection("conversations/" + messageID + "/messages").where("timestamp", ">=", time)
```

What security rules will allow me ensure that time in function b is somewhat close to the current time?

Thanks!

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: The reason I tagged both is both users would have faced similar issues since both allow snapshots (RD just calls it the on function for listeners) and both have very similar security rules.

Comment: I am not really understanding the result you are looking for here. The question isn't clear on it's expectation.

Comment: db.collection(path).where("timestamp", ">=", time) -- lets say time here is Date.now() - aka time as of now. What secruity rule would allow me to make sure time is current time and not yesterday, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.time` for when the specific document was created, which is type of [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp), as stated in the [Rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time).

I found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915616/firebase-firestore-timestamp-based-security-rules) which might help as well.