# Check with Firestore security rules if optional dates and maps have valid types

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestore security rules we can check the types of optional strings and lists as follows:

```
function reviewFieldsAreValidTypes(docData) {
  return docData.get('photo_url', '') is string &&
         docData.get('tags', []) is list;
}
```

What would one use as the default value for optional timestamps?

```
docData.get('dateModified', ???) is timestamp;
```

And for an optional map?

```
docData.get('translated', ???) is map;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase firestore timestamp based security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915616/firebase-firestore-timestamp-based-security-rules)

Comment: No, 
docData.get('dateModified', request.time) is timestamp;

isnt working either.

Comment: Can you clarify what *isn't working* means? Is there an error or message? What's the result? Did you do this -> `Make sure that 'myServerTimestampField' was set using a server-side timestamp`

Comment: My mistake, it does work, the unit test was wrong.

Comment: Do you by any chance have more wisdom to impart regarding the second part of my question, the maps? docData.get('translated', ???) is map;

Comment: I'm using request.resource.data now for the default map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to set a default value of the correct type. We can use the request object:

```
function reviewFieldsAreValidTypes(docData) {
  return docData.get('photo_url', '') is string &&
         docData.get('tags', []) is list &&
         docData.get('dateModified', request.time) is timestamp &&
         docData.get('translated', request.resource.data) is map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct solution for your question, but you have an option to use a condition like the posted code below:

```
// resource.data.keys => check if the key exists. 

if !("dateModified" in resource.data.keys()) || (resource.data.dateModified is timestamp)

if !("translated" in resource.data.keys()) || (resource.data.translated is map)
```

Just a note, keep in mind that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) when writing queries to retrieve documents.

Comment: Your solution definitely works but my question was specifically about using the get notation. Based on Jay's link and within that an additional link I have found it works to use: 

docData.get('dateModified', request.time);
docData.get('translated', request.resource.data) is map; 

It just needs a default value of the correct type.

Comment: I suggest that you post your own answer so that other community members can also see it. Also check this [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)