# Firestore security rules for birthdate

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I would like to have a Firestore security rule for bithdate field in my users collections where user age should be >=18 and <=80. I tried the following rule but I know it is not going to work especially for ages that are close to 18 or 80.  Any idea how to make this work.

```
let now = request.time;
let thisYear = now.year();
let thisMonth = now.month();
let thisDay = now.day();

request.resource.data.birthdate >= timestamp.date(thisYear-80,thisMonth,thisDay) && 
request.resource.data.birthdate <= timestamp.date(thisYear-18,thisMonth,thisDay)
```

Comment: Why won't this one work? Can you explain "close" values? Alternative would be to use `duration` but that should return same results.

Comment: I believe it does not work because I am not taking care of the time.  There could be some time difference between "birthdate" coming from the client and the timestamp in the server.

Comment: can you tale a look at my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result by comparing it with the request time but in seconds.  here’s one example on how this will work:

```
function isAbove18(date) {
return date.seconds <= request.time.seconds - 18 * 365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60; //considering leap year with 0.25  
}
function isBelow80(date) {
return date.seconds >= request.time.seconds - 80 * 365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60;
}

allow read, write: if isAbove18(resource.data.birthdate) && isBelow80(resource.data.birthdate);
```

For more about this you can go through this [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50915685/20239914) which takes some different approaches.